# How to addClass click and removeClass when click again outside or click other element?

Tags: javascript, nodes, ecmascript-5

This is my code. I want to when `dblclick` in element `<li>` active event and `removeClass` when click outside or click into other element.

```
  initTodoITem: function (todo, lbContent, inputEdit) {
   var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.setAttribute('class', 'todoItem');

    item.addEventListener('dblclick', function (){
      lbContent.classList.add('edit');
      inputEdit.classList.remove('edit');
      inputEdit.classList.add('editing');
    });

    return item;
  },
```

Comment: The whole idea is, look for that selector as an ancestor when clicking in the outer containing element (or `document`) and if not, check and/or remove class. It's very simple, actually.

Comment: @Jared Farrish l started learning javascript, I do not know how to write syntax or flow of the command. Please help me make a small example.